# Data changed during request transfer from Ext JS to Java

Tags: java, jsp, extjs

I am sending data from Ext JS to my Java code through ajax request, but it get changed at java side.

```
                Wtf.Ajax.requestEx({
                url: "MyJspPage.jsp",
                params: {
                    requestType: 1,
                    htmlcode: "Chào"
                },
                method: 'POST'
            },
            this,
            function (response, request) {
            });
```

but at java side it becomes

```
String htmlcode=request.getParameter("htmlcode");
```

String htmlcode contains value "ChÃ o"

Comment: You have a missmatch of the character encoding between the sending and receiving side.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson Thank you sir, would you please tell me where and how to set it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `escape` function for character encoding. Then your `extjs` code will be like

```
Wtf.Ajax.requestEx({
 url: "MyJspPage.jsp",
 params: {
   requestType: 1,
   htmlcode: escape("Chào")
 },
 method: 'POST'
},
 this,
 function (response, request) {
});
```

Comment: Use `unescape` function eg. `unescape(escape("Chào"))`

Comment: would you please tell me one more thing, how to un-escape this code in java?

Comment: Use `URLDecoder.decode(htmlcode, "UTF-8")` to unescape in java

Comment: I use this, but it gives error - 


URLDecoder.decode(html encode, "UTF-8") = >Exception occurred in target VM: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u1"< in java

Comment: Then try this instead `ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String result = (String) engine.eval("unescape('" + htmlcode + "')");`

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying encoding in JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```